# Bind an event handler to a React ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and I'm creating a wizard style registration component with several steps. I am loading my sub-components with a ref called `currentStepComponent` so I can call an `executeAction` function on them. This execute function will basically submit the form in the sub-component.

```
<Component ref={this.currentStepComponent} />
<button onClick={() => {this.currentStepComponent.current.executeAction()}}>
    Next Step
</button>
```

The sub-component renders a form that is crated with ref so I can submit it.

```
executeAction() {
    //Trigger Submit
    this.formRef.current.submit();
}

handleFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //his never runs, the form just submits.
    ...
}

render() {
    return (
        <form 
            onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}
            ref={this.formRef}
        >
    );
}
```

The problem I'm having is my submit handler isn't being attached to the form when I use a ref. I have tried several different ways to attach this event handler to my submit event and it misses it. I have created a workspace here: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-dan-x1i7b?file=/src/App.js

How do I attach the `handleFormSubmit` to my formRef? Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: Why are you using a ref here? Instead of `this.formRef.current.submit()`, just call the `handleFormSubmit` function.

Comment: Because I want the native validation to run before the form is submitted.